# Sudden slow-down and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError during Java string search

Tags: java, string, search, memory, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program for pattern discovery in RNA sequences that mostly works. In order to find 'patterns' in the sequences, I am generating some possible patterns and scanning through the input file of all sequences for them (there's more to the algorithm, but this is the bit that is breaking). Possible patterns generated are of a specified length given by the user.

This works well for all sequence lengths up to 8 characters long. Then at 9, the program runs for an very long time, then gives a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. After some debugging, I found that the weak point is the pattern generation method:

```
/* Get elementary pattern (ep) substrings, to later combine into full patterns */
public static void init_ep_subs(int length) {

ep_subs = new ArrayList<Substring>(); // clear static ep_subs data field

/* ep subs are of the form C1...C2...C3 where C1, C2, C3 are characters in the
   alphabet and the whole length of the string is equal to the input parameter
   'length'. The number of dots varies for different lengths.
The middle character C2 can occur instead of any dot, or not at all.*/

for (int i = 1; i < length-1; i++) { // for each potential position of C2

    // for each alphabet character to be C1
    for (int first = 0; first < alphabet.length; first++) { 

    // for each alphabet character to be C3
    for (int last = 0; last < alphabet.length; last++) {

        // make blank pattern, i.e. no C2
        Substring s_blank = new Substring(-1, alphabet[first],
                          '0', alphabet[last]);

        // get its frequency in the input string
        s_blank.occurrences = search_sequences(s_blank.toString());

        // if blank ep is found frequently enough in the input string, store it
        if (s_blank.frequency()>=nP) ep_subs.add(s_blank);

        // when C2 is present, for each character it could be
        for (int mid = 0; mid < alphabet.length; mid++) {

        // make pattern C1,C2,C3
        Substring s = new Substring(i, alphabet[first],
                        alphabet[mid],
                        alphabet[last]);

        // search input string for pattern s
        s.occurrences = search_sequences(s.toString());

        // if s is frequent enough, store it
        if (s.frequency()>=nP) ep_subs.add(s);
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

Here's what happens: When I time the calls to search_sequences, they start out at around 40-100ms each and carry on that way for the first patterns. Then after a couple hundred patterns (around 'C.....G.C') those calls suddenly start to take about ten times as long, 1000-2000ms. After that, the times steadily increase until at about 12000ms ('C......TA') it gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
    at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.toString(HeapCharBuffer.java:542)
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.toString(CharBuffer.java:1157)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.toMatchResult(Matcher.java:232)
    at java.util.Scanner.match(Scanner.java:1270)
    at java.util.Scanner.hasNextLine(Scanner.java:1478)
    at PatternFinder4.search_sequences(PatternFinder4.java:217)
    at PatternFinder4.init_ep_subs(PatternFinder4.java:256)
    at PatternFinder4.main(PatternFinder4.java:62)
```

This is the search_sequences method:

```
/* Searches the input string 'sequences' for occurrences of the parameter string 'sub' */
public static ArrayList<int[]> search_sequences(String sub) {

/* arraylist returned holding int arrays with coordinates of the places where 'sub'
 was found, i.e. {l,i} l = lines number, i = index within line */
ArrayList<int[]> occurrences = new ArrayList<int[]>();
s = new Scanner(sequences);
int line_index = 0;

String line = "";
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    line = s.nextLine();
    pattern = Pattern.compile(sub);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    pattern = null; // all the =nulls were intended to help memory management, had no effect

    int index = 0;

    // for each occurrence of 'sub' in the line being scanned
    while (matcher.find(index)) {
    int start = matcher.start(); // get the index of the next occurrence
    int[] occurrence = {line_index, start}; // make up the coordinate array
    occurrences.add(occurrence); // store that occurrence
    index = start+1; // start looking from after the last occurence found
    }
    matcher=null;
    line=null;
    line_index++;

}
s=null;

return occurrences;
}
```

I've tried the program on a couple of different computers of differing speeds, and while the actual times time complete search_sequence are smaller on faster computers, the relative times are the same; at around the same number of iterations, search_sequence starts taking ten times as long to complete.

I've tried googling about memory efficiency and speed of different input streams such as BufferedReader etc, but the general consensus seems to be that they are all roughly equivalent to Scanner. Do any of you have any advice about what this bug is or how I could try to figure it out myself?

If anyone wants to see any more of the code, just ask.

EDIT:

1 - The input file 'sequences' is 1000 protein sequences (each on one line) of varying lengths around a couple hundred characters. I should also mention this program will /only ever need to work/ up to patterns of length nine.

2 - Here are the Substring class methods used in the above code

```
static class Substring {
int residue; // position of the middle character C2
char front, mid, end; // alphabet characters for C1, C2 and C3
ArrayList<int[]> occurrences; // list of positions the substring occurs in 'sequences'
String string; // string representation of the substring

public Substring(int inresidue, char infront, char inmid, char inend) {
    occurrences = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    residue = inresidue;
    front = infront;
    mid = inmid;
    end = inend;
    setString(); // makes the string representation using characters and their positions
}

/* gets the frequency of the substring given the places it occurs in 'sequences'. 
   This only counts the substring /once per line ist occurs in/. */
public int frequency() {
    return PatternFinder.frequency(occurrences);
}

public String toString() {
    return string;
}

/* makes the string representation using the substring's characters and their positions */
private void setString() {
    if (residue>-1) {
    String left_mid = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < residue-1; j++) left_mid += ".";
    String right_mid = "";
    for (int j = residue+1; j < length-1; j++) right_mid += ".";
    string = front + left_mid + mid + right_mid + end;
    } else {
    String mid = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length-2; i++) mid += ".";
    string = front + mid + end;
    }
}
 }
```

... and the PatternFinder.frequency method (called in Substring.frequency()) :

```
public static int frequency(ArrayList<int[]> occurrences) {
    HashSet<String> lines_present = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int[] occurrence : occurrences) {
        lines_present.add(new String(occurrence[0]+""));
    }
    return lines_present.size();
    }
```

Comment: You algorithm has O^3 complexity (maybe O^4)! Can't you improve it?

Comment: With an alphabet of 4 letters (ACGT) that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Forget your code for a moment (which seems to have a fundamental flaw in its approach). What exactly are you trying to do? If you provide a brief description and some sample input/output, maybe we can help you write a good algorithm.

Comment: @JimGarrison: of course, he is working with proteins. I forgot that.

Comment: My bet is on the `Substring` class. Can you post the source?

Comment: You are of course all correct that the algorithm could be improved, but I still don't understand why it gives results for patterns of length eight in just a couple of minutes, then completely breaks for patterns of length nine.

Comment: There are NP-complete problems that explode in this way, such as the Traveling Salesman problem. For n=5 there are 12 paths. For n=20 it's several hundred thousand, and for n=60 there are more paths than atoms in the known universe.

Comment: Please show the source for the Substring class.

Comment: Also, how many characters are in the string `sequences`, and how many lines?  Notice that it's dying in `hasNextLine()`.  This is probably significant.

Comment: I also don't think the regexes are the problem, since they're not recursive (don't contain any variable-length patterns such as asterisks).  They should work in linear time.

Comment: @JimGarrison added Substring class.

Answer (score 0):

What is alphabet? What kind of regexs are you giving it? Have you checked the number of occurrences you're storing? It's possible that simply storing the occurrences is enough to make it run out of memory, since you're doing an exponential number of searches.

It sounds like your algorithm has a hidden exponential resource usage. You need to rethink what you are trying to do.

Also, setting a local variable to null won't help since the JVM already does data flow and liveness analysis.

Edit: [Here's a page that explains how even short regexes can take an exponential amount of time to run.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: Alphabet is {"A","C","G","T"}.
The regexs are the patterns themselves, so [letter][some dots][optional letter][some dots][letter], e.g. 'A..A.G' will match 'AAGATG' in the input.
Occurrences are at least 500 (otherwise the pattern is not considered frequent enough).
Thanks for the clarification about how null works, that was so dubious.

Comment: It sounds like your regexes are strictly linear time. In that case, the problem is probably memory exhaustion from storing results. Either that or the matching function is internally copying your data.

Answer (score 0):

I can't spot an obvious memory leak, but your program does have a number of inefficiencies.  Here are some recommendations:

1. Indent your code properly.  It will make reading it, both for you and for others, much easier.  In its current form it's very hard to read.
2. If you're referring to a member variable, prefix it with `this.`, otherwise readers of code snippets won't know for sure what you're referring to.
3. Avoid static members and methods unless they're *absolutely* necessary.  When referring to them, use the `Classname.membername` form, for the same reasons.
4. How is the code of `frequency()` different from just `return occurrences.size()`?
5. In `search_sequences()`, the regex string `sub` is a constant.  You need to compile it only once, but you're recompiling it for every line.
6. Split the input string (`sequences`) into lines once and store them in an array or `ArrayList`.  Don't re-split inside `search_sequences()`, pass the split collection in.

There are probably more things to fix, but this is the list that jumps out.

Fix all these and if you still have problems, you may need to use a profiler to find out what's happening.